# Software for working with fusion categories

Tags: topological-quantum-field-theory, mathematical-software, fusion-categories, braided-tensor-categories, modular-tensor-categories

One way to describe fusion categories is via a fusion system: several lists of numbers that define the fusion ring, associator, braiding (if it exists), etc. Often, these sets of numbers are quite big, and to check properties, computer algebra systems can be a big help.
At the moment I am finishing my Ph.D. thesis, which describes a Mathematica package [Anyonica](https://github.com/gert-vercleyen/Anyonica) that I developed for working with multiplicity-free fusion rings and categories. This is not the only package/software that provides functionality to do this, though.
For example

- Recently W. Aboumrad has published a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.00831) describing SageMath functionality to calculate and work with ribbon fusion categories coming from quantum groups. It is open source and uses parallelization and clever heuristics to find solutions. At this moment, it only deals with multiplicity-free fusion categories AFAIK.
- E. Ardonne has a [Mathematica package](https://github.com/ardonne/affine-lie-algebra-tensor-category) that finds fusion categories by calculating Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for fusion rings coming from quantum groups. This is the only package I know of that can categorify fusion rings with multiplicity.
- T. Hagge and M. Titsworth have a [Mathematica package](https://mktitsworth.com/fusion-categories/) that contains data on fusion rings and categories and some methods to work with these. I can't
- The [GitHub repository](https://github.com/JCBridgeman/smallRankUnitaryFusionData) of J. Bridgeman contains data on all unitary multiplicity-free fusion categories up to rank 6. This data has also been incorporated in the [TensorKit.jl](https://github.com/Jutho/TensorKit.jl) package from J. Haegeman via the extension [CategoryData.jl](https://github.com/lkdvos/CategoryData.jl) from L. Devos.
- [Kac](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Et58/Site/Kac.html), from B. Schellekens (and others?), can be used to compute fusion rules for Rational Conformal Field Theories based on affine Lie Algebras and their simple current extensions
- F. Meuser and U. Thiel are developing [tensorcategories.jl](https://github.com/FabianMaeurer/TensorCategories.jl), a package that provides a framework as well as examples for computations in the realm of categories.
- Z. Liu, S. Palcoux, and Y. Ren have [implemented](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.10264) various categorifiability criteria in SageMath.
- S. Palcoux also has [several implementations](https://sites.google.com/view/sebastienpalcoux/fusion-rings?authuser=0) of SageMath code to find fusion rings with certain properties.
- [Normaliz](https://github.com/Normaliz/Normaliz) now also includes functionality to find fusion rings.

Writing such software often takes a lot of time, and a good researcher is not necessarily a good promoter of their software.

So, is there other software that I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

In the new version (3.10.2) of [Normaliz](https://github.com/Normaliz/Normaliz/releases/tag/v3.10.2), Winfried Bruns is set to introduce an optimized function for classifying all fusion rings based on their type and duality, with a particular focus on the integral case. For more details, see Appendix H in [this manual](https://github.com/Normaliz/Normaliz/blob/master/doc/Normaliz.pdf).

Regarding fusion categories, Section 10 of the TPE paper [arXiv:2203.06522v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.06522v2) outlines a method for deriving valuable subsystems from the pentagon equations of a specified fusion ring:

- For instance, it provides a subsystem of 45 equations with 34 variables for the isotype variation of ch(PSL(2,8)), see its fusion data in Appendix. It is the smallest non-group-like simple integral fusion ring for which the categorification into a complex fusion category remains open. It would be a non weakly group-theoretical integral fusion category, see [[ENO11](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2010.06.009), Question 2]). The existence of a solution to this subsystem was open for over three years. However, on January 10, 2024, Paul Breiding successfully found a solution employing [homotopy continuation](https://www.juliahomotopycontinuation.org/).
- Additionally, it identifies a subsystem consisting of 26 equations and 25 variables for the fusion ring associated with the exotic modular data of rank 11, as introduced in [arXiv:2308.09670](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.09670) (see the fusion data also below in Appendix).

---

*Appendix*

Fusion data of the isotype variation of ch(PSL(2,8)):
[[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]],[[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2],[1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1]]]

Fusion data of the exotic MD of rank 11 in the introduction of [arXiv:2308.09670](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.09670):
[[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]],[[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2]],[[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,2],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2]],[[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,2,2]],[[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]],[[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3],[0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,2],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],[0,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],[0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2],[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],[0,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3],[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],[1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4],[0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4]],[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],[0,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,2,2],[0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3],[0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],[0,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],[0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],[0,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3],[0,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4],[1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4]]]

Comment: Hey Sebastien, I knew some methods in the mentioned paper were used to find subsystems, but I couldn't find any code. Is this code open source? 
It's great that Normaliz will have this functionality in the future! Once it does, I'll add it to the list above :)

Comment: Hi Gert, yes I made a code providing such subsystems. I will try to share it in the future version of the TPE paper.

Comment: @Gert That's it! Normaliz 3.10.2 just released. See the new links I added.

Comment: I have added Normaliz to the list in the question. Thanks! I also added a reference to my thesis (together with a reference to the paper where you described the SageMath code for the categorifiability criteria) :)
I will take a short vacation now since I handed in the thesis yesterday, and I'm super tired. After that, I'll look into the Zesting some more